# Use SVG componets in a monorepo shared UI library without webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, yarn-workspaces, turborepo

Hello everyone I have a Yarn, Turborepo monorepo. I have 2 Next apps that share some UI components

```
src
|- apps/ the next js apps
|- packages/ui the UI  library
```

I am unable to add SVGR as I don't have webpack, I use NextJS transpile to get the library into my project. What are my options to import SVGs it my code? I am currently failing during the build

[My setup is the same as this](https://github.com/leoroese/turborepo-tutorial)

Most of my confusion comes from how the compilation and builds happen with monorepos

Next transpiles the library, but library itself fails during build as SVG files cannot be imported

Basically I am trying to do this

`import Star from './star.svg'`

In a [shared library like this](https://github.com/leoroese/turborepo-tutorial/tree/main/packages/ui)

Do I need to create a react app for this? I am suspecting that I need a more complex setup with proper build step, outputs and entry point for the types

Comment: @NicholasHaley I just used the SVGR CLI, could probably add a build step or something, but honestly, it was super hard to get other stuff working so I didn't tinker with this any further.

Comment: Gotcha, yes that is what I am leaning toward as well

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with Next.js and SVG import ending up here.

You can follow the [SVGR implementation for Next.js](https://react-svgr.com/docs/next/) to import the SVG as a React component, and use the Next.js feature [transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages) to include the ones outside your project.

It wasn't working for me, but I realized that my problem was related to having the import inside a [React Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components). I solved that by isolating the element with the SVG in a separate file, adding ["use client"](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive) at the top.